# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una celda de una tabla con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una parte de ventas y pues, lleno la tabla con datos y lo que quiero es, que al hacer clic sobre una fila se copie el dato del total en una variable. Para al momento de eliminar algo de la venta, irlo restando al total.

Aquí está el enlace de lo que viene siendo el código.

http://itszas.edu.mx/sgpv/Pruebas_Alexis/Ventas.php

Los productos que ya están en la base de datos, son _Chocoalte Yogurt Plum_a

Apenas comienzo con esto de la programación web, tal vez sea fácil pero no puedo.

```html
<?php

 include("conexion.php");
 $sql="SELECT nombre,precio FROM productos";  
 $ejecutar = mysql_query($sql);

  $con=0;
  while($reg=mysql_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
   $arrayPHP [$con] [0] = $reg[0];
   //echo"Cont vale: $con";
   $arrayPHP [$con] [1] = $reg[1];       
   $con=+$con+1;
  // echo"Nombre: $reg[0]";
  // echo"<br>";
       // echo"Precio: $reg[1]";
  // echo"<br>";
   
   //echo"<br>";
        } 
  //echo $arrayPHP[1][1]; 
  //echo"<br>";
  //echo $arrayPHP[0][1];
  ///echo"<br>"; 
 // echo"Valor del array en la primer posisión: $arrayPHP[0][0]";
?>

<!Doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<style>
 #content{
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
 }
#texto{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
color: black;
    text-align: center;
font-size: 50px;
}

a{
 color:#e44e2d;
 font-weight:bold;
}

 .selected{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .selected:hover{
  background-color: #0585C0;
  color: white;
 }
 .seleccionada{
  background-color: #0585C0;
  color: white;
 }
</style>
<script>
 var total = parseInt(0);
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#bt_add').click(function(){
   agregar();
  });
  $('#bt_del').click(function(){
   eliminar(id_fila_selected);
  });
  $('#bt_delall').click(function(){
   document.getElementById("total_venta").innerHTML="Total: 0";
   total = 0;
   eliminarTodasFilas();
  });
  

 });
 var cont=0;
 var id_fila_selected=[];

 function agregar(){
  cont++;
  var sum1 = "";
  var encontro = 0;
  var precio = parseInt(0);
  var precio1 = "";
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
    var Id=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
   var arrayJS=<?php echo json_encode($arrayPHP);?>;
  
   for(var i=0;i<arrayJS.length;i++){
    if(Id == arrayJS[i][0]){
     encontro = 1;
    precio = parseInt(arrayJS[i][1]);
    precio1 = precio;
    var cantidad2 = parseInt(cantidad);
    precio = precio * cantidad2;
    //var total = (parseInt(precio) + parseInt(total));
    total = total + precio;
   }
     }
   
   if (!cantidad){
       alert('No puedes dejar vacío el campo de texto cantidad :(');  
   }else{
   if(cantidad == 0){
    alert('No puedes introducir cerukis');
   }else{
    if(encontro == 1){
     document.getElementById("total_venta").innerHTML="Total: "+total;
     //var fila='<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>'+cont+'</td><td>'+Id+ '</td> <td>'+cantidad+'</td> <td>'+precio1+'</td><td>'+precio+'</td></tr>';
     
     var fila='<tr class="selected" prec="'+precio+'" id="fila'+cont+'" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>'+cont+'</td><td>'+Id+ '</td> <td>'+cantidad+'</td> <td>'+precio1+'</td><td>'+precio+'</td></tr>';
     
     
     $('#tabla').append(fila);
     reordenar(); 
     }else{
      alert('El producto no existe :( Si acaba de agregar el producto regarge la página ;)'); 
     }
    }
   }
   }
  

  
 function seleccionar(id_fila,prec){
  //alert('Holi me picaste ahí shi' + prec );
  if($('#'+id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')){
   $('#'+id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
  }
  else{
   $('#'+id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
  }
  //2702id_fila_selected=id_fila;
  id_fila_selected.push(id_fila);
 }

 function eliminar(id_fila){
  /*$('#'+id_fila).remove();
  reordenar();*/
  //alert('El id de la filuki es:' + id_fila);
  for(var i=0; i<id_fila.length; i++){
   $('#'+id_fila[i]).remove();
  }
  reordenar();
 }

 function reordenar(){
  var num=1;
  $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function(){
   $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
   num++;
  });
 }
 function eliminarTodasFilas(){
$('#tabla tbody tr').each(function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });

 }


</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="content">
     <div id = texto>
      <label>Ventas</label>
     </div>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Producto a comprar" id="nombre" class="formulario">
        <input type="number" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad a comprar" id="cantidad" class="formulario">
  <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</button>
  <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar</button>
  <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar todo</button>
  <h2 id = "total_venta">Total: 0</h2>
        <br>
  <table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Nº</td>
    <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
    <td>Precio</td>
                <td>total</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
     <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-default">Cobrar</button>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo que usas jQuery así que en mi ejemplo lo uso también, he simplificado el código pero puedes hacer algo así:

```js
$("table tbody tr").click(function() {
  var total = $(this).find("td:last-child").text();
  alert(total);
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>3.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>2.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

He usado la pseudoclase `:last-child` para llegar al último `td` pero si no está en todas las filas o no siempre es el último `td` podrías poner una clase distinta a la celda del total.

Comment: Exacto, si la celda es cambiante lo suyo es que defina una clase por ejemplo clase `valor` y recurra a `.valor` en lugar de `td:last-child`. Buena respuesta

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que quieras alguna columna en especifica puedes usar el método o selector :eq(3), .eq(3) y especificar el indice de la columna deseada.

> **Selector** .find("td:eq(3)").text()
>
> **Metodo** .find("td").eq(3).text()

```js
$("table tbody tr").click(function() {
  var total = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text();
  alert(total);
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>3.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>2.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hola @Hector Lara ,como haria para obtener el el valor de un input dentode de un td , dentro de un each, estoy intentado pero no me sale.  $('#tabla2 tbody tr').each(function() {  var precio = $(this).find('td').eq(5).text();
      var cantidad = $(this).find('input').eq(6).val();

Comment: En lugar de usar .eq(5).text() debes buscar dentro del td seria entonces .eq(5).children('input').val() eso ta daria el valor del imput